# Which settings are required to run Ansible on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I've configured a new Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance. and added my public ssh key to the server.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -I aws.pem ubuntu@<ec2publicDNS> "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2"
```

I'm now able to access the instance with

```
ssh ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
```

So I added the following to my `/etc/ansible/hosts`

```
[webservers]
ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
```

when I'm running `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible all -m ping` I receive the following:

```
  9264 1486122587.48735: starting run
  9264 1486122587.58557: Loading CacheModule 'memory' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/cache/memory.py
  9264 1486122587.62315: Loading CallbackModule 'minimal' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
  9264 1486122587.62373: Loading CallbackModule 'actionable' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/actionable.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.62388: Loading CallbackModule 'context_demo' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/context_demo.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.62401: Loading CallbackModule 'debug' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/debug.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.62420: Loading CallbackModule 'default' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.62450: Loading CallbackModule 'foreman' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/foreman.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63003: Loading CallbackModule 'hipchat' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/hipchat.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63048: Loading CallbackModule 'jabber' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/jabber.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63064: Loading CallbackModule 'json' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/json.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63096: Loading CallbackModule 'junit' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/junit.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63121: Loading CallbackModule 'log_plays' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/log_plays.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63173: Loading CallbackModule 'logentries' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/logentries.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63266: Loading CallbackModule 'mail' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/mail.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63273: Loading CallbackModule 'minimal' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63288: Loading CallbackModule 'oneline' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/oneline.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63304: Loading CallbackModule 'osx_say' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/osx_say.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63321: Loading CallbackModule 'profile_tasks' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63648: Loading CallbackModule 'skippy' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/skippy.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63678: Loading CallbackModule 'slack' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/slack.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63755: Loading CallbackModule 'syslog_json' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/syslog_json.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63772: Loading CallbackModule 'timer' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/timer.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63789: Loading CallbackModule 'tree' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/tree.py (found_in_cache=False, class_only=True)
  9264 1486122587.63795: in VariableManager get_vars()
  9264 1486122587.63812: done with get_vars()
  9264 1486122587.64662: Loading StrategyModule 'linear' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py
  9264 1486122587.64819: getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  9264 1486122587.64824: done getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  9264 1486122587.64832: building list of next tasks for hosts
  9264 1486122587.64838: getting the next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122587.64846: done getting next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122587.64852:  ^ task is: TASK: meta (flush_handlers)
  9264 1486122587.64859:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=1, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  9264 1486122587.64863: done building task lists
  9264 1486122587.64868: counting tasks in each state of execution
  9264 1486122587.64872: done counting tasks in each state of execution:
    num_setups: 0
    num_tasks: 1
    num_rescue: 0
    num_always: 0
  9264 1486122587.64876: advancing hosts in ITERATING_TASKS
  9264 1486122587.64881: starting to advance hosts
  9264 1486122587.64885: getting the next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122587.64892: done getting next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122587.64896:  ^ task is: TASK: meta (flush_handlers)
  9264 1486122587.64901:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=1, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  9264 1486122587.64907: done advancing hosts to next task
  9264 1486122587.65149: done queuing things up, now waiting for results queue to drain
  9264 1486122587.65157: results queue empty
  9264 1486122587.65161: checking for any_errors_fatal
  9264 1486122587.65164: done checking for any_errors_fatal
  9264 1486122587.65168: checking for max_fail_percentage
  9264 1486122587.65171: done checking for max_fail_percentage
  9264 1486122587.65175: checking to see if all hosts have failed and the running result is not ok
  9264 1486122587.65180: done checking to see if all hosts have failed
  9264 1486122587.65186: getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  9264 1486122587.65190: done getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  9264 1486122587.65198: building list of next tasks for hosts
  9264 1486122587.65202: getting the next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122587.65208: done getting next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122587.65212:  ^ task is: TASK: ping
  9264 1486122587.65216:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  9264 1486122587.65220: done building task lists
  9264 1486122587.65224: counting tasks in each state of execution
  9264 1486122587.65228: done counting tasks in each state of execution:
    num_setups: 0
    num_tasks: 1
    num_rescue: 0
    num_always: 0
  9264 1486122587.65232: advancing hosts in ITERATING_TASKS
  9264 1486122587.65235: starting to advance hosts
  9264 1486122587.65238: getting the next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122587.65244: done getting next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122587.65248:  ^ task is: TASK: ping
  9264 1486122587.65252:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  9264 1486122587.65256: done advancing hosts to next task
  9264 1486122587.65263: getting variables
  9264 1486122587.65269: in VariableManager get_vars()
  9264 1486122587.65297: done with get_vars()
  9264 1486122587.65308: done getting variables
  9264 1486122587.65313: sending task start callback, copying the task so we can template it temporarily
  9264 1486122587.65318: done copying, going to template now
  9264 1486122587.65324: done templating
  9264 1486122587.65329: here goes the callback...
  9264 1486122587.65336: sending task start callback
  9264 1486122587.65342: entering _queue_task() for ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>/ping
  9264 1486122587.65349: Creating lock for ping
  9264 1486122587.65468: worker is 1 (out of 1 available)
  9264 1486122587.65510: exiting _queue_task() for ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>/ping
  9264 1486122587.65575: done queuing things up, now waiting for results queue to drain
  9264 1486122587.65582: waiting for pending results...
  9267 1486122587.65922: running TaskExecutor() for ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>/TASK: ping
  9267 1486122587.65987: in run()
  9267 1486122587.66061: calling self._execute()
  9267 1486122587.67436: Loading Connection 'ssh' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py
  9267 1486122587.67554: Loading ShellModule 'csh' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/csh.py
  9267 1486122587.67589: Loading ShellModule 'fish' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/fish.py
  9267 1486122587.67632: Loading ShellModule 'powershell' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/powershell.py
  9267 1486122587.67649: Loading ShellModule 'sh' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/sh.py
  9267 1486122587.67672: Loading ShellModule 'sh' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/sh.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
  9267 1486122587.67693: in VariableManager get_vars()
  9267 1486122587.67736: done with get_vars()
  9267 1486122587.67764: Loading ActionModule 'normal' from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/normal.py
  9267 1486122587.67774: starting attempt loop
  9267 1486122587.67783: running the handler
  9267 1486122587.67827: ANSIBALLZ: Using lock for ping
  9267 1486122587.67831: ANSIBALLZ: Acquiring lock
  9267 1486122587.67837: ANSIBALLZ: Lock acquired: 4559072080
  9267 1486122587.67841: ANSIBALLZ: Creating module
  9267 1486122587.75433: ANSIBALLZ: Writing module
  9267 1486122587.75461: ANSIBALLZ: Renaming module
  9267 1486122587.75472: ANSIBALLZ: Done creating module
  9267 1486122587.75528: _low_level_execute_command(): starting
  9267 1486122587.75537: _low_level_execute_command(): executing: /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486122587.76-200107609248376 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1486122587.76-200107609248376="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486122587.76-200107609248376 `" ) && sleep 0'
  9267 1486122590.52707: stdout chunk (state=2):
>>>ansible-tmp-1486122587.76-200107609248376=/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486122587.76-200107609248376
<<<

  9267 1486122590.52765: stdout chunk (state=3):
>>><<<

  9267 1486122590.52775: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>><<<

  9267 1486122590.52795: _low_level_execute_command() done: rc=0, stdout=ansible-tmp-1486122587.76-200107609248376=/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486122587.76-200107609248376
, stderr=
  9267 1486122590.52808: transferring module to remote /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486122587.76-200107609248376/ping.py
  9267 1486122590.53337: Sending initial data
  9267 1486122590.53347: Sent initial data (139 bytes)
  9267 1486122590.54550: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>ssh: Could not resolve hostname <ec2publicIP>]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
<<<

  9267 1486122590.54583: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>Connection closed
<<<

  9267 1486122590.54612: stdout chunk (state=3):
>>><<<

  9267 1486122590.54618: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>><<<

 [WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information

  9267 1486122590.54711:
  9267 1486122590.54718: ssh: Could not resolve hostname <ec2publicIP>]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Connection closed

  9267 1486122590.56466: stderr chunk (state=2):
>>>ssh: Could not resolve hostname <ec2publicIP>]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
<<<

  9267 1486122590.56501: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>lost connection
<<<

  9267 1486122590.56525: stdout chunk (state=3):
>>><<<

  9267 1486122590.56534: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>><<<

 [WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information

  9267 1486122590.56573:
  9267 1486122590.56577: ssh: Could not resolve hostname <ec2publicIP>]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
lost connection

  9267 1486122590.56621: done running TaskExecutor() for ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>/TASK: ping
  9267 1486122590.56628: sending task result
  9267 1486122590.56669: done sending task result
  9267 1486122590.56674: WORKER PROCESS EXITING
  9264 1486122590.56785: in VariableManager get_vars()
  9264 1486122590.56925: done with get_vars()
  9264 1486122590.56939: marking ubuntu@<ec2publicIP> as failed
  9264 1486122590.56947: marking host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP> failed, current state: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  9264 1486122590.56952: ^ failed state is now: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_COMPLETE, fail_state=FAILED_TASKS, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  9264 1486122590.57203: getting the next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122590.57211: host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP> is done iterating, returning
ubuntu@<ec2publicIP> | FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "failed to transfer file to /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1486122587.76-200107609248376/ping.py:\n\nssh: Could not resolve hostname <ec2publicIP>]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known\r\nlost connection\n"
}
  9264 1486122590.57242: no more pending results, returning what we have
  9264 1486122590.57251: results queue empty
  9264 1486122590.57255: checking for any_errors_fatal
  9264 1486122590.57259: done checking for any_errors_fatal
  9264 1486122590.57262: checking for max_fail_percentage
  9264 1486122590.57265: done checking for max_fail_percentage
  9264 1486122590.57269: checking to see if all hosts have failed and the running result is not ok
  9264 1486122590.57272: done checking to see if all hosts have failed
  9264 1486122590.57275: getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  9264 1486122590.57279: done getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  9264 1486122590.60734: building list of next tasks for hosts
  9264 1486122590.60741: getting the next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122590.60748: host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP> is done iterating, returning
  9264 1486122590.60752: done building task lists
  9264 1486122590.60755: counting tasks in each state of execution
  9264 1486122590.60759: done counting tasks in each state of execution:
    num_setups: 0
    num_tasks: 0
    num_rescue: 0
    num_always: 0
  9264 1486122590.60768: all hosts are done, so returning None's for all hosts
  9264 1486122590.60773: done queuing things up, now waiting for results queue to drain
  9264 1486122590.60777: results queue empty
  9264 1486122590.60780: checking for any_errors_fatal
  9264 1486122590.60785: done checking for any_errors_fatal
  9264 1486122590.60789: checking for max_fail_percentage
  9264 1486122590.60793: done checking for max_fail_percentage
  9264 1486122590.60796: checking to see if all hosts have failed and the running result is not ok
  9264 1486122590.60802: done checking to see if all hosts have failed
  9264 1486122590.60809: getting the next task for host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP>
  9264 1486122590.60813: host ubuntu@<ec2publicIP> is done iterating, returning
  9264 1486122590.60818: running handlers
  9264 1486122590.60893: RUNNING CLEANUP
```

do I have to expose some extra ports in my security_group in aws? Until now only port 22 is exposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your hosts file:

```
[webservers]
<ec2publicIP> ansible_user=ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1):

Ansible uses ssh, so port 22 is enough, you won't need any additional Security Groups for you EC2 instance. What you might do is modify your inventory and instead of `<username>@<ipaddress>` use only `<ipaddress>` (or resolvable name). You can `remote_user` in your playbook, or specified it with `ansible_user` in your inventory as Konstantin pointed out.